# Fast way to compare frequent input data and storing MAX and MIN values

Tags: c, performance, embedded

Let's say I have input data every millisecond.
After 5 seconds I want to output the MAX and MIN Value of the last 5 second time window.

What will be here the fastest way to compare frequent integer input data? I put a very simple example. Is it bad to use something like this in general? Is there a faster way but without using array for buffering?

```
myMainFuntion() {
    int static currentMIN = 30000; // Just initialize to a value that will never be output by getSensorData
    int static currentMAX = 0;
    int static acquisition_counter = 0;

    a = getSensorData() // called each 1 ms
    if (a > currentMAX) {
       currentMAX = a;
    }

    if (a < currentMIN) {
       currentMIN = a;  
    }

    acquisition_counter++;

    if (acquisition_counter == 5000) {
        output(MAX);
        output(MIN);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking - 1ms is *very* slow compared to a handful of comparison operations.

Comment: How __slow__ is you cpu?

Comment: If you are willing to scroll past the geeksforgeeks- and leetcode-garbage, a search for sliding window maximum in your favorite search engine may be helpful.

Comment: Depending on the expected value range you're dealing with, there may be a clever solution that's faster than a simple ring buffer.  If you ask a generic question, you'll get a generic answer.  Add detail if you absolutely need to squeeze out performance for this particular problem.

Comment: @paddy:  I removed some parts of the Question. Now assuming the factor embedded and time critical is here not relevant. Its now to the algorithm as itself.

Comment: After the 5 seconds, what happens next? Is that the end?  If the goal is an _ongoing_ min/max of last 5 seconds, other approaches should be considered.  Does the min/max reset or should a min/max get outputted every millisecond after 5.0s?  Else all we have here of the min/max of 5000 samples.

Comment: @chux MIN and MAX is for statistic use and yes it will be output each 5s

Comment: JohnDoe Then [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53308546/2410359) has a good solution although I would initialize with `currentMIN = INT_MAX; currentMAX = INT_MIN;` and avoid magic numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems OK, there is not much to be optimized in your function, except for a few details:

- the return type should be `void` instead of omitted.
- `a` is not defined.
- you should output `currentMIN` and `currentMAX` instead of `MIN` and `MAX`.
- you should reset the values of the min and max variables after the output.
- it is more idiomatic to ut the `static` keyword in front of the type.

Here is the modified code:

```
void myMainFuntion(void) {
    static int currentMIN = 30000; // Just initialize to a value that will never be output by getSensorData
    static int currentMAX = 0;
    static int acquisition_counter = 0;
    int a;

    a = getSensorData() // called every 1 ms
    if (a > currentMAX) {
       currentMAX = a;
    }
    if (a < currentMIN) {
       currentMIN = a;  
    }

    acquisition_counter++;
    if (acquisition_counter == 5000) {
        output(currentMAX);
        output(currentMIN);
        currentMAX = 0;
        currentMIN = 30000;
        acquisition_counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: chqrlie, true, if the first sample was the min value and all others larger, my suggestion would fail.  Removed.

Comment: @chqrlie - regarding the reset of min and max after output. That would be as per the particular use case. It may or may not be required. In any case the rest of `acquisition_counter` is required